# mongoose get collections that not includes certain item in sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

this is my schema

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
    },
    cost: {
    },
    students: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId,
            fullName: String,
            email: String
        }
    ]
});
```

I have student **John Doe** with `objectId: "something"`
, in mongoose how can I get courses that not include john doe? in simple words show him courses that he doesn't buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `$ne` operator to do this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "students._id": {
    $ne: "id123"
  }
})
```

I've created an example for you on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/t9AyVVT9mAX